# Sort elements based on time windows

Tags: java, sorting, collections

I need to sort elements based on time windows, e.g.

```
8:00 - 9:00 
8:00 - 11:00 
9:00 - 10.00 
9:00 - 12:00
```

So far my idea is to sort open times and close times as separate `Maps`, and then try to create the final `List` `sortedList`. I'm not sure however that this idea is the most efficient solution. Is there any way to solve this issue in the easier way?

```
private List<Customer> sortCustomersByTimeWindows(List<Customer> _C)
{
List<Customer> sortedList = new ArrayList<Customer>();      

Map<Integer,Integer> openTimes = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();
Map<Integer,Integer> closeTimes = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>();

for (int i=0; i<_C.size(); i++)
{
    openTimes.put(i,_C.get(i).getOpenTime());
    closeTimes.put(i,_C.get(i).getCloseTime());
}

List<Integer> openTimes_values = new ArrayList<Integer>(openTimes.values());
List<Integer> closeTimes_values = new ArrayList<Integer>(closeTimes.values());

Collections.sort(openTimes_values, new Comparator<Integer>() {
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return o1 - o2;
    }
});

Collections.sort(closeTimes_values, new Comparator<Integer>() {
    public int compare(Integer o1, Integer o2) {
        return o1 - o2;
    }
});

for (int i=0; i<_C.size(); i++)
{
    //...
}

return sortedList;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just use a custom comparator that sorts your customers based on the times:

```
Collections.sort(_C, new Comparator<Customer>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Customer c1, Customer c2) {
        int openTimeDiff = c1.getOpenTime() - c2.getOpenTime();
        if (openTimeDiff != 0)
            return openTimeDiff;
        return c1.getCloseTime() - c2.getCloseTime();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could have a map of Integer, Integer that maps from the opening time to the closing time
Then you can sort by keys or by values

```
Collections.sort(_C, new Comparator<Customer>() {
    public int compare(Customer o1, Customer o2) {
        return //the test case here for times or whatever you need
    }
});
```

Comment: Do you mean this? Map<Integer,Integer> times = new HashMap<Integer,Integer>(); ... times.put(_C.get(i).getOpenTime(),_C.get(i).getCloseTime()); In this case how to sort by open and close times?

Comment: Aslo, I need to keep a track of 'i', because it is connected with id of Customer

Comment: You can get an iterator over the keyset or value collection

Comment: Thanks. Could you please provide some short example of your ideas?

Comment: In that case, I'd recommend sorting the list of customers and implementing the compare() method to make it compare opening / closing times. With no separate arrays for the times

Comment: I appreciate if you can give a small example.

Comment: Collections.sort(_C, new Comparator<Customer>() {
    public int compare(Customer o1, Customer o2) {
        return //the test case here for times or whatever you need
    }
});